# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'companyName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to solve this error but I'm stuck and need help  to solve this since I'm new to angularjs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'companyName' of undefined
     at Scope.$scope.companyModify (app.js:8501)
     at $parseFunctionCall (base.js:21610)
     at callback (base.js:30772)
     at Scope.$eval (base.js:23672)
     at Scope.$apply (base.js:23771)
     at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (base.js:30777)
     at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (base.js:4430)
     at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (base.js:4116)
```

---

```
$scope.companyModify = function(company) {
    var param = {
        companyName: $scope.companyName,
        billColumn: $scope.billColumn,
        billTitle: $scope.billTitle,
        serviceTax = $scope.serviceTax,
        wishMessage = $scope.wishMessage,
        billTypeId = $scope.billTypeId
    };

    SocketService.post(apiManage.apiList['CompanyModify'].api, param).then(function(resp) {
        var data = resp.data.response;

        if (data.status === true) {
            angular.forEach($scope.companyList, function(value) {
                if (value.billTypeId == billTypeId) {
                    value.$edit = false;
                }
            });

            Notify.alert(data.message, {
                status: 'success',
                pos: 'top-right',
                timeout: 5000
            });
            $scope.load();

        } else {
            Notify.alert(data.message, {
                status: 'danger',
                pos: 'top-right',
                timeout: 5000
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: use scope.ComponyName it looks you injected scope in place of $scope.

Comment: where the value $scope.companyName comes from ?

Comment: companyName comes from Company table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your object 'param' is wrongly constructed.

can you please try  -

```
var param = {
    companyName: $scope.companyName,
    billColumn: $scope.billColumn,
    billTitle: $scope.billTitle,
    serviceTax: $scope.serviceTax,
    wishMessage: $scope.wishMessage,
    billTypeId: $scope.billTypeId
};
```

there are '=' signs which should be replaced by ':'

Secondly, please make sure all the variables, companyName, billColumn.. etc are attached to the model, i.e $scope before you call the method - **$scope.companyModify()**

Let me know if this helps.